# Why does this WebSocket function return too many messages?

Tags: javascript, ruby, websocket, sinatra

I'm using Ruby gems `sinatra` and `sinatra-websocket` on the backend, with JS on the frontend.

My backend:

```
get '/' do 
    if(!(request.websocket?))
        erb :index
    else 
        request.websocket do |ws|
            ws.onopen do
                settings.sockets << ws 
            end

            ws.onmessage do |msg|
                EM.next_tick {
                    settings.sockets.each{|s|
                        # p s
                        s.send(msg)
                    }
                }
            end

            ws.onclose do
                warn("connection closed")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And on the frontend...

```
window.onload = function(){
    function someFunction(){
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.host+window.location.pathname);
        ws.onopen = function(){
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons');
            [].forEach.call(
                buttons,
                function(btn){
                    if(btn!=null){
                        btn.onclick = function(){
                            var amt = 11;
                            ws.send(amt);
                            console.log(amt);
                            return false;
                        };
                    }
                }
            );
        };
        ws.onmessage = function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            return false;
        };

        ws.onclose = function(){
            console.log("Connection closed");
            return false;
        };
    }
};
```

The first `console.log()` prints `test` once, but the one in `onmessage` gives the response twice at first, three times the second time I click one of the `buttons`, and more times every time I click afterward.

Why is this? How do I make it so the function in `onmessage` gives me `msg` just once each time I click one of the `buttons`?